# Cant include /usr/include/linux files

Tags: c++, linux, cmake

This may come as a newbie question, but I am having a very porous knowledge of C++/CMake and only a slightly better understanding of linux itself.

The situation: I am sitting at an Debian 8 operated machine as a normal user (no root available) and I am trying to compile the code written by someone else (yeah, I know, not the best working scenario).

All libraries are now installed on my machine, but I am now getting this error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/posix1_lim.h:160:0,
                 from /usr/include/limits.h:143,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/include-fixed/limits.h:168,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/include-fixed/syslimits.h:7,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/include-fixed/limits.h:34,
                 from /usr/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:55,
                 from /usr/include/opencv2/opencv.hpp:47,
                 from /home/*.hpp:3,
                 from /home/*.h:4,
                 from /home/*.cpp:1:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/local_lim.h:38:26: fatal error: /usr/include/linux/limits.h: Keine Berechtigung
 #include <linux/limits.h>
```

The second last line is german "Keine Berechtigung" and means "No permission".

As I said, I have little understanding of cpp/cmake but I would have guessed that I am able to read whats inside the /usr/include/linux folder, but it turns out I cant and thus I cant compile/run the code. And I dont think the person who wrote the code had root permissions either.

So, where is the real problem here? Wrong permission handling and I should contact the admin?

Comment: ***So, where is the real problem here?*** I would start by looking at the permissions of the files in `/usr/include/linux` For me on gentoo all files are  owned by root:root but have read access for owner group and other.

Comment: That did the trick. I am farely knew to his specific setup and I just contected the admin. Forgot to set some flags. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@drescherjm was right, I should have gotten read access to that folder. I knew it was a basic question but my knowledge of linux never got into the areas of `/usr/include` ;)